# Solution to restrict number of connections to oracle using multithread in JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a thread in which it creates a connection to oracle DB, reads the contents and writes to csv file. In each thread contents from DB are written to separate csv file. As there are n number of connections established to DB, it throws an exception saying "ORA-00018: maximum number of sessions exceeded". Please provide a solution to stop it but code should run in the same time. Here below is the code used.

```
  host s1 = new host(SYSNAME,SYSID);
  s1.start();

  class host extends Thread{
     String SYSNAME,SYSID;
     public host(String SYSNAME, String SYSID){
        this.SYSNAME = SYSNAME;
        this.SYSID = SYSID;
     }
     public void run(){
        Connection conn;
    try{
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, pwd);
        String csv_file = "AverageValuesHost-" + SYSNAME + "-" + SYSID +  "_Result.csv";
        String host_query = null;
        host_query = "My query";
        ResultSet res_host = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(host_query);

        CSVWriter wr = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csv_file), ',');
        wr.writeAll(res_host, true);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();
        conn.close();
    }
```

Comment: The database only allows so many connections to it. Use a connection pool (c3p0 or dbcp) or increase the number of connections you can establish (modify the oracle's maximum number of connections).

Comment: @Kiran: you need to restructure your code such that getting the connection to the DB should be from a connection pool(synchronized). Your threads need to access that connection pool and get the connection to DB,If there are no connection, your thread should go to sleep.

Comment: @Lathy: Hope you did not understood my question. Because there is no point of synchronization as all the thread has it own functionality. Threads are not dependent

Comment: @honerlawd: Yes, increasing the number of connection is one of the option. But I don't think that is the best way. Because two or more users run this code, I again get same error.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a `DataSource` with connection pooling to create your connections (eg C3P0 or HikariCP). This allows you to specify the maximum number of connections, and when connections aren't available, the thread is forced to wait (upto a timeout) until a connection is available.

Also note that creating more threads isn't always the best way to get more work done. You could also consider using an [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) with a fixed number of threads, and submit the jobs to this executor service. That way there are never more than *n* jobs running at a time, so you can limit the number of connections that way.

Just make sure you always close your connections (which your current code isn't doing correctly when exceptions occur). Look at [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Answer (score 0):

can you try something like this. 
1. Create custom thread and have db connection initialized in that CustomThread
2. Create a ThreadPoolExecutor to fixedThreadPool() passing no of connection as parameter, also this TPE should take a custom thread factory
3. Create a Runnable class, and access 
3. For each query make a runnable and submit to bq.
4. Do not use any wait/notify/ or any other synchronization inside your Runnable. Once a Runnable is starts executing inside your Thread, it will complete the execution of the Runnable. It takes lock on underlying Thread. [from TPE code]

This is an unorthodox approach, I never seen a Runnable is taking a object out of Thread(custom) class to execute. But I don't find any issue in this, some one can correct me if I am wrong.

I made a prototype, please have a look and let me know if it serves your purpose.
Well, this can be improved in lot ways, like exception handling, rejection handling etc. But first the happy path or purpose should be achieved.

Thanks

```
package com.stackoverflow.dbconpool;

import java.sql.Connection;

public class DBConnectionThread extends Thread {
    Connection con;

    public Connection getCon() {
        return con;
    }

    public DBConnectionThread(Runnable r) {
        super(r);
        con = null;// initialize with parameters to make a connection with db.
        // if you want any custom parameter to be passed, you can create a
        // separate Runnable
        // and take values from that runnable to initialize DBConnectionThread.
    }

}


package com.stackoverflow.dbconpool;

import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;

public class DBConnectionThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {

    @Override
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        DBConnectionThread t = new DBConnectionThread(r);
        return t;
    }
}



package com.stackoverflow.dbconpool;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.Random;

public class ExecuteQueryRunnable implements Runnable {

    Random rand;
    int index;

    public ExecuteQueryRunnable(Random rand, int i) {
        this.rand = rand;
        this.index = i;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Executing DB Query " + index + " inside $$"
                + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        long threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();
        DBConnectionThread thread = (DBConnectionThread) Thread.currentThread();
        Connection con = thread.getCon();
        // // execute query code, stament creation etc etc.
        System.out.println("completed executing DB query -" + index
                + "- inside $$" + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        long threadIdFinish = Thread.currentThread().getId();
        if (threadIdFinish != threadId)
            System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
    }
}


package com.stackoverflow.dbconpool;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class TestMultiDB {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3,
                new DBConnectionThreadFactory());
        // BlockingQueue<ExecuteQueryRunnable> queryQueue = new
        // ArrayBlockingQueue<ExecuteQueryRunnable>(
        // 10);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Runnable r = new ExecuteQueryRunnable(rand, i);
            es.execute(r);
        }
        es.shutdown();

        while (!es.isTerminated()) {
        }
        System.out.println("main terminates ");
    }
}
```

Comment: fantastic try. But this slowing down the speed. Since in my case 2000 files to be created each has data of 1000 entries.